# Getting Exception javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android

I Know that we have to handle certificate on server side, but now have to work in that way in android. I get that excption on this line
androidHttpTransport.call(strSoapAction, envelope);
but then too I want to handle the exception and ignore for now and get the response
Please help
I have written this code in AsyncTask, doInBackground
Bellow is my code,  is a way to by pass https exceptions?
I have used this now, http://blog.syedgakbar.com/2012/07/android-https-and-not-trusted-server-certificate-error/
but how to sent request and response further?

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("https://something.something.com/", "method");
String strSoapAction = "https://something.something.com/method";
request.addProperty("strObjectName", arrParams[0]);
request.addProperty("strCommand", arrParams[1]);
request.addProperty("strXMLParameters", arrParams[2]);
SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
envelope.dotNet=true;

envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport =  null;
androidHttpTransport = new       HttpTransportSE("https://db.server.com/some.asmx"); 


androidHttpTransport.call(strSoapAction, envelope); //getting exception over here
Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trusting all certificates using HttpClient over HTTPS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2642777/trusting-all-certificates-using-httpclient-over-https)

Comment: Yes i know this, but how to go further with request and response?